# Display author bio box

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have post page with author info. But it seems author bio box should only display if content has been entered. How to check it?

```
<?php if(get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )) != 0){
    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 80);
}?>
<div class="post-full-desc">
    <h6><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></h6>
    <p><?php echo get_the_author_meta('description')?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You question is not clear. Is `the_author_posts_link()` not printing author name? or `get_the_author_meta()` not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check author description field is empty or not, if not empty then you wanna show it?

```
<?php if( get_the_author_meta( 'description', $id ) != ''):?>
    <div class="post-full-desc">
        <h6><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></h6>
        <p><?php echo get_the_author_meta('description')?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```